# How to reinitialize AngularJS 1 Controller for only 1 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 HTML Element with the same Controller but different ng-init('value').

**HTML**

```
<div id="open-status" ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="init('open')">
    <div ng-repeat="status in statusList">
        {{ status.name }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="closed-status" ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="init('closed')">
    <div ng-repeat="status in statusList">
        {{ status.name }}
    </div>
</div>

<button id="reload-open-status-only">Reload</button>
```

**Javascript/Jquery/AngularJS**

```
.controller("MainController", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.init = function(myType) {
    dataService.ajaxThis($config).then( function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.statusList = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        // ERROR: NO RESPONSE FROM THE AJAX URL
        alert('Ajax error! Status not fetched. Please try again later.');
    });
    $scope.$on('reloadMe', function(e, args){
        $scope.init(args);
    })
});

$(document).on('click', '#reload-open-status-only', function($rootScope, $timeout){
    $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('reloadMe', 'open');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Now, this is working fine. The problem is both of my element are reloading. What is the right way to reload a single ng-controller without using different angular controllers.

**EDIT**

added a parameter to my broadcast like this

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('reloadMe', 'open', 'open-status');
```

and to my controller

```
angular.element($('#' + id)).scope.init(args);
```

but i'm having an error:

```
angular.element(...).scope.init is not a function
```

Comment: What do you mean by "both of the elements are reloading?"

Comment: both #open-status and #closed-status are running new init since they both have the same controller.

Comment: You should include both divs and the buttons are part of the view.  Instead of having the same status list - split it into 2 - openStatusList and closedStatusList.  Is that something you can do?

Comment: same controller doesn't mean same instance....each will have it's own controller instance and scope....and won't know about the other

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish? Each list updates the other? Or keep them completely separate?

Comment: update the open-status list. and keep the other one as it is.

Comment: could store your list type in controller and only reload the one you want by checking which type it is first when the `$on()` fires

Comment: @charlietfl there's an edit in my question please refer. i really want to avoid multiple ajax request per update

Comment: Making it even more complicated even using jQuery for any of this. Really should have an outer controller also and use a service to bind all this together and get rid of jQuery completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.element($('#' + id)).scope().init(args);

worked .. just added () after scope.